# NodeJs/Electron, Request Post not catching Request Body

Tags: node.js, electron, npm-request

I've got some simple code that isn't working. Have tried several libraries, all of which wind up giving me similar errors. I'm convinced the website itself is somehow rejecting the request. It's wrapped in an electron application.

This is the response I receive (not a typical error - the error is in the response body)

```
{"error":{"code":2,"message":"Query missing. `Are ya gonna search for something or what?`"}}
```

This is a snippet of relevant code, present in the main.js of my app:

```
const request = require('request');
.
.
.
ipcMain.on('request-mainprocess-action', (e, args) => {

request({ body: JSON.stringify({"query": {"status": {"option": "online"}, "stats": [{"type": "and", "filters": []}]},"sort": {"price": "asc"}}}),
 followAllRedirects: true,
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   'Referer': 'www.pathofexile.com/trade/search/Incursion',
   'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Incursion'}, callback);

function callback(error, response, body) {

    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        e.sender.send('mainprocess-response', {
            type: args.query,
            data: body
        });
    } else {
        console.log(body);
    }
}
});
```

I've tried a few variations of this, like calling request.post or using a json object and the flag json:true. I've also tried some other libraries, like http, https, and axios(axiom?).... No luck.

I was able to make it work with little effort using an IntelliJ http post script/snippet:

```
POST https://www.pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Incursion
Referer: https://www.pathofexile.com/trade/search/Incursion
Content-Type: application/json,
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

{"query": {"status": {"option": "online"}, "stats": [{"type": "and", "filters": []}]},"sort": {"price": "asc"}}
```

The above returns a rather large bit of text,

```
Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 1426ms; Content length: 6755 bytes
```

Unfortunately I cannot call this from Electron :)... Could really use your help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your request-headers:

```
'Host': 'www.pathofexile.com',
```

And here is the complete code which I run it from my side with node command:

```
const request = require('request');


var payload = JSON.stringify({"query": {"status": {"option": "online"}, "stats": [{"type": "and", "filters": []}]},"sort": {"price": "asc"}});

request({ 
        body: payload, 
        followAllRedirects: true,
        headers: {
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           'Referer': 'www.pathofexile.com/trade/search/Incursion',
           'Host': 'www.pathofexile.com',
           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://pathofexile.com/api/trade/search/Incursion'}, callback);

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log('Success: \n'+body);
    } else {
        console.log("Error: \n"+body);
    }
};
```

And I got this result as shown on this screenshot:
[image]